# How can I make a POST request in Postman with two different dataset?

Tags: postman

I am trying to make a post call in Postman, but I want it to iterate 3 times (say) each  time with different set of data. How can I do so?

Comment: Run postman 3 times, each time with different data set?

Comment: Can you use variables and set them in your pre-request script based on the dataset you need?

Answer (score 0):

First you can not specify the backend technology. 
E.x if you use node js Or java you have to just create only one api and call it 3 times in back end with different parameter. For that you don't need to call or create 3 times api in postman .

Answer (score 0):

you can define presents. Open 3 tabs and copy and paste the request URL. Then import presents in each tab.

Answer (score 0):

you can put your data into a CSV file and then follow this: 
http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/10/28/using-csv-and-json-files-in-the-postman-collection-runner/

Answer (score 0):

set variables in your JSON body and use a data file (CSV or JSON), in postman runner, to update them at each iteration.

see http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/10/28/using-csv-and-json-files-in-the-postman-collection-runner/

If you have three different values for a variable, it will do 3 iterations automatically

This could help.